# Filtering entity set with lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, wcf-ria-services

So I have this on the server

```
public IQueryable<Pos>GetPos(int programID)
    {
        var entitySet = _posRepository.All().Where(x => x.ProgramID == programID).Include("RecPositions.Person");

        return entitySet.Where(x => x.RecPositions.Any(rp => rp.PosRank != 0));
    }
```

I have similar/same? code on the client. But figured this should be done on the server so I dont potentially bring back thousands of records. Im expecting the (rp => rp.PosRank != 0) to omit any records that have a 0...but for some reason it isnt. Can someone take a look and let me know if I am missing something. Again i want all PosRank records that are 0 to not be included in result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is currently saying to include any entities which have *any* RecPositions with a non-zero PosRank.

It's not filtering the RecPositions returned within the entities - it's filtering their *parent* type (Pos).

if you only want to include Pos entities where *all* the RecPositions have a non-zero PosRank, you simply want:

```
return entitySet.Where(x => x.RecPositions.All(rp => rp.PosRank != 0));
```

If you really want the RecPosition values (instead of the Pos values), you might want:

```
return entitySet.SelectMany(x => x.RecPositions)
                .Where(rp => rp.PosRank != 0));
```

Comment: @Jon...have a bit of an issue still with this..So when i get all the positions and recPositions and Person with that include..then filter out any that have recPosition.posRank != 0..what this seems to be doing is..that I have for example a Center Position and I have in my RecPosition entity a count of 2. one person has a rank of 1 and one has a rank of 0..that filter seems to remove both of them so that RecPosition seems to be empty now. Hope this make sense..

Comment: @Jon..after some work this was exactly what I needed. i went another direction that you led me down. I basically did the second example you left. I need to originally filter on the position but after that I really didnt need that entity anymore so I did the selectmany and reworked some other code. Much better doing this on the server since there is a chance of thousands of rows and this way we only bring back about 10 rows per position...thanks!